# Operating on multiple rows in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to operate on all rows of the result of groupby.
Basically I have something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def tdiff(dff):
#    return(dff[dff.task.eq('d')].start - dff[dff.task.ne('d')].end)
    return(dff[dff.task.eq('d')].start - dff.end)

a = []
p = 0
while p < 6:
    i = 0
    while i < 4:
        a.insert(i,p)
        i = i + 1
    p = p + 1

d={'task':pd.Series(6*['a','b','c','d'],name='task'),
    'jobid':pd.Series(a),
    'start':pd.Series(np.random.randn(24)),
    'end':pd.Series(np.random.randn(24))}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

dt = df.groupby('jobid').apply(tdiff)
dt.name='tdiff'
print(type(dt))
print(dt)
```

Except I have more than a dozen different 'tasks' (a,b,c,d,....z) in each group. And not all groups are guaranteed to have all the tasks except task 'd' is guaranteed. There will be atleast 1 more task beside task 'd'.

In each groupby result I want to get difference between *d.start* and *end* of all other tasks. 
How do I do this?

I've tried an apply function and that does seem to return a series. But I get NaN for everything other than 'd'. I guess I am not sure how to subtract d.end from 'start' values of all other tasks in each group.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [`pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`sub()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
df2 = df.pivot(columns="task", index="jobid")
df2.end.sub(df2.start.d, axis=0)
```

With `df` generated from OP code as:

```
         end  jobid     start task
0  -1.223702      5 -0.458517    a
1   0.045843      5 -0.676103    b
2  -0.661233      5  1.213528    c
3  -0.339473      5  0.090109    d
4   2.474916      4  0.069272    a
5   0.562003      4  0.307962    b
6   0.286008      4 -0.045996    c
7   0.770700      4  1.053486    d
8  -0.948754      3 -0.173639    a
9   0.576441      3 -1.085345    b
10  0.098523      3  1.399861    c
11  0.983254      3 -0.976588    d
12 -0.286155      2 -0.542215    a
13 -1.959281      2 -0.436720    b
14  1.020525      2  1.050937    c
15  0.815528      2  2.173647    d
16  0.158771      1 -2.584689    a
17  0.239464      1  0.521442    b
18  0.463753      1 -0.919359    c
19  0.430110      1 -0.996819    d
20  0.084908      0  0.599807    a
21  0.615123      0 -1.563351    b
22 -0.027279      0 -0.755369    c
23  0.826941      0  2.228655    d
```

Output of `sub()`:

```
task          a         b         c         d
jobid                                        
0     -2.143747 -1.613532 -2.255934 -1.401714
1      1.155591  1.236284  1.460572  1.426930
2     -2.459802 -4.132928 -1.153122 -1.358119
3      0.027834  1.553029  1.075111  1.959842
4      1.421430 -0.491483 -0.767478 -0.282786
5     -1.313812 -0.044266 -0.751343 -0.429582
```